# Get-VpnConnection reports `Invalid class`

Tags: powershell

I am running PSVersion 5.1.14393.206. Is there something that I must configure or call before `Get-VpnConnection`?

```
PS C:\Users\pwatson> Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection
Get-VpnConnection : Invalid class
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (PS_VpnConnection:root/Microsoft/...S_VpnConnection) [Get-VpnConnection], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Get-VpnConnection
```

Same result in 64-bit and 32-bit shell.

Comment: Shot in the dark but have you tried running this from a 32-bit shell assuming you are not already? For whatever reason it looks like the wmi provider PS_VpnConnection is not available.

Comment: @Matt - Good idea, but produces the same results.

Comment: I can run it on PS 5.0 without admin rights, in 64bit PS. No VPNs and no output, but it doesn't crash. Makes me think you might have something corrupt (e.g. in WMI). [Here](http://clintboessen.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/wmi-error-invalid-class-0x80041010-fix.html) is someone investigating the same error code from a different WMI class - have you looked in the Event Logs for a related message?

Answer (score -1):

if you doesn't have VPN connection use you will get error but if u have use this :

```
Get-VpnConnection
```

your output will your VPN information . 
you don't need any thing for this service .

Comment: The thing is, I am on a VPN connection right now. Perhaps the answer is that it only recognizes Microsoft VPN connections.

Comment: @Liturgist : can u explain more plz ?