# Add-VpnConnectionRoute : Invalid class error on Powershell 5.1

Tags: windows, powershell, vpn

I am trying to add a connection for a company lab VPN network by running the following `Powershell` command:

```bash
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -Name VPN_NAME -DestinationPrefix 192.168.18.0/24 -RouteMetric 500
```

and the error that I am receiving is the following:

```
Add-VpnConnectionRoute : Invalid class 
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-VpnConnectionRoute -Name VPN_NAME -DestinationPrefix 192. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (PS_VpnConnectionRoute:root/Microsoft/...ConnectionRoute) [Add-VpnConnectionRoute], Cim 
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Add-VpnConnectionRoute
```

There is already a [question regarding this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359214/get-vpnconnection-reports-invalid-class), but it is left unanswered, so I decided to start a new thread.

Powershell version:

| Major | Minor | Build | Revision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 19041 | 3570 |

I tried running the command on `Powershell` with and without admin rights.

I also tried `Powershell ISE`, and it includes all the `VpnClient` commands that I have tried to use, so I suppose the `VpnClient` module is already existent in the system:

[image]

Comment: Possibly corrupt WMI database? https://superuser.com/a/1152468/65498

Comment: I cannot confirm that it was a WMI database issue although it could have been. I am using a managed, work computer so I had to contact our internal support to proceed with the fix asap. That is because I could not run some instructions on the link you provided (needed privileges for it). Thank you anyway